# Angular2/Javascript - Retrieve the new value of the variable that was generated inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, angular

I am willing to retrieve the value of a variable that was updated inside a for loop and access it outside of the scope.

For this I have:
**Page.html**

```
<div [options]="Pages">
  <div *ngFor="#cat of category">
        <div class="newCategory">The new category will appear here!</div>
  <div>
</div>
```

**Page.js**

```
constructor(viewCtrl, http, navParams) {
   this.viewCtrl  = viewCtrl;
   this.navParams = navParams;
   this.http      = http;
   this.category  = null; 

   this.http.get('https://website.com/api', { search }).subscribe(data => {
     this.category = data.json().results; 
   }); 

  //I want to print the new value of 'this.category' here
  //e.g: console.log(this.category); 

  this.Pages = {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    slidesPerView: 1,
    paginationClickable: true,
    paginationBulletRender: function (index, className) { 
     //also I want to access it here  
     return '<span class="' + className + '">' + this.category[index+1] + '</span>';
    }
  }
}
```

Do I need to have a global variable in order to read the new value of the variable? Or do I need something else?

Comment: Where should the `category` value for the new category come from?

Comment: It will come from the REST API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to store `this.category` and loop it in an array, then you'll be able to get the stored value outside of the `this.http.get()`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the question is about. A guess:

```
 <div class="newCategory">{{cat}}</div>
```

The constructor needs to be changed

```
constructor(viewCtrl, http, navParams) {
        this.viewCtrl = viewCtrl;
        this.navParams = navParams;
        this.http = http;
        this.category = null;

        this.http.get('https://website.com/api', { search }).subscribe(data => {
        this.category = data.json().results;
       //I want to print the new value of 'this.category' here
       //e.g: console.log(this.category);


              this.Pages = {
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            slidesPerView: 1,
            paginationClickable: true,
           paginationBulletRender: function (index, className) {


           //also I want to access it here 


           return '<span class="' + className + '">' + this.category[index+1] + '</span>';
            }
            }


        });
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want it this way as I don't need it, what I want is to get it on the JS/Angular code.

Comment: For the edit you've just made, what service that needs to be changed? Please elaborate more

Comment: `http.get()` is executed async and the code after `subscribe(...)` is executed before the data arrives. Sometimes later when the data arrives from the server the code passed to `subscribe(...)` is called. You need to execute the code that handles received data inside the `subscribe(...)` callback.

Comment: Sorry `constructor` not `service`. This code is usually in a service (not necessary but it's good practice)

Comment: When I take this.Pages, and insert it inside this.http.get, I don't see anything, only a blank page!

Comment: So, that value can not be used outside of the scope?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "scope". You can't use it before it arrived from the server. Put a `console.log('data arrived)` before  `this.category = data.json().results;` and check if it is printed, otherwise you don't even get data from the server. If this is printed then check if `this.category` is printed at `//e.g: console.log(this.category);`

Comment: I placed it as you advised, I received 'data arrived'; however, when I try to print `console.log(this.category)` after the `this.http.get()` I get `null`